# How to flawlessly apply a (created) model on new data in R?

Tags: r, model, prediction

Sorry if it feels like a repeated question but honestly speaking, I've spent more than 12 hours on this and haven't yet found easy to understand and easy to apply method.

The situation is simple, I've  created 2 models and need to apply them to the test data.

```
#Model 1 -

reg5 <- glm(train$survived ~ train$pclass_str + train$sex + 
             train$age_2 + train$sibsp + train$pclass_str*train$sex, 
             family = "binomial")

#Model 2 - 
reg6 <- randomForest(train$survived_str ~ train$pclass_str + train$sex + 
                      train$age_2 + train$sibsp, ntree=5000)
```

## Applying it -

```
test$pred_reg5 <- predict(reg5, newdata = test, type="response")
test$pred_reg6 <- predict(reg6, newdata = test, type="response")
```

What I can assure is that both train and test data contain the variables used in the models by the same name. Though there are other unused variables.

The error I'm getting:

```
Error in `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, keep, value = c("0", "1", "1", "1", "0",  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 418 rows but variables found have 891 rows
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your models to, e.g.:

```
reg5 <- glm(survived ~ pclass_str + sex + age_2 + sibsp + pclass_str*sex, 
            data=train, family = "binomial")
reg6 <- randomForest(survived_str ~ pclass_str + sex + age_2 + sibsp, 
                     data=train, ntree=5000)
```

There may be another problem with your model specification in that `reg5` uses `survived ~...` and `reg6` uses `survived_str ~...`, but I can't tell from your question if this is an issue.

Finally, as @Roland points out, you can simplify your formulas. If you're going to do this a lot, read the documentation on formula in R (`?formula`). In R formulas, interactions are built by specifying `a:b`. The notation `a*b` is equivalent to `a + b +a:b` (e.g., first order terms + their interaction). So, specifying `pclass_str*sex` is equivalent to specifying `pclass_str + sex + pclass_str:sex`.

Comment: Thanks, it would be good if you explained why it is better to use the `data` parameter. The first formula could also be simplified to `age_2 + sibsp + pclass_str*sex`.

Comment: this was superb!! I did try using this format earlier but probably mixed up and failed. It solved another error for me. I was not able to put 'Importance = TRUE' argument in randomForest earlier but now it works. Thanks a ton! Also, any quick input on the difference between predict and predict.glm?

Comment: @jlhoward i read some tutorials and there the analyst was using survived as factor in case of randomForest so I did. This was not causing my issue.

Comment: @PreritAhuja I think there is no difference between predict and predict.glm - the predict function "dispatches" different model input types to various particularised predict functions. Try typing `methods(predict)` to see them all (or those loaded in base R)